# NSOutputStream. How load stream sound in file?

Tags: iphone

Please help me, how load sound in file with NSOutputStream ?
This is posible or no ? If no, what will help me ?

Answer (score 2):

NSOutputStream is way off in terms of audio output. Since this comes with the `iPhone` tag, you can look at the [`AV Foundation`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVFoundationFramework/_index.html) framework. You would be better off starting with the [`programming guide`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AVFoundationPG/Articles/00_Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010188).